# How to plot all points that are defined by $(4\kappa+2(\lambda \mod 2), 2\lambda\sqrt 3)$ in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

How to plot all points that are defined by $(4\kappa+2(\lambda\mod2),  \ 2\lambda\sqrt 3)$ for some $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ that are integers in Wolfram Alpha?
I just want to know what this set of points looks like (I need it to understand a research paper).
Thank you.

Comment: Is this a mapping from $(\lambda, \kappa)\to (f(\lambda,\kappa), g(\lambda, \kappa))$?

Comment: @caverac I guess

Comment: In that case you need to be more specific, are you looking for a particular domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use Wolfram|Alpha. Use a [Wolfram Cloud Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) command similar to 

`ListPlot[Table[{4 k + 2 Mod[n,2], 2 n Sqrt[3]}, {k,-3,3}, {n,-4,4}]]`

The points form a [Hexagonal lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_lattice) in the plane which determines a tiling by equilateral triangles.